# PyQt5 - Making QCombobox Drop List On Hover

Tags: python, pyqt5

So Basically I Am newbie In PyQt5, I found that the PyQt5 support stylesheets!

So I just thought Of The implementing that drop a list when i user hover on QCombobox.

Any Answer Or Suggestion Is Accepted!

Can it be?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout,
                             QComboBox, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        combo = QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem('Disk')
        combo.setItemIcon(0, QIcon('disk.png'))
        
        combo.addItem('Web')
        combo.setItemIcon(1, QIcon('web.png'))

        combo.addItem('Computer')
        combo.setItemIcon(2, QIcon('computer.png'))

        hbox.addWidget(combo)
        hbox.setSpacing(20)
    
        self.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 180)
        self.setWindowTitle('QComboBox')
        self.show()


def main():
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please avoid capitalization of Every Word In Your Questions, as it makes it difficult and annoying to read it.

Comment: Just Made Some Changes For the The Capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylesheets in Qt do not allow programmatical access to widget functions (with [some exceptions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) for widget properties, which *must* be used with care, though).
So, if you thought you could use stylesheets to show the popup on hover, you can't.

In order to do that, you must subclass the QComboBox and reimplement its [`enterEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent), otherwise install an event filter. In both cases, you need to call [`showPopup()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#showPopup):

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        combo.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            source.showPopup()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Note that if you want to filter other widgets and different event types, it's better to create a reference for the object(s) and check that the source of the event is actually what you need:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.installEventFilter(self)
        # ...

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.combo and event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            source.showPopup()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

About the customization with stylesheets, see the examples on [customizing QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox), but I also warmly suggest you to *study* both the stylesheet [syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) and [reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) documentation.

<sub>Also note that you should always ask one question per post, if you have more different questions, create a post for each of them.</sub>

Comment: Thank You For Answer And I Look Forward For Stylesheets

Comment: You're welcome, but please stop using word capitalization, it's *very* annoying.